# How to set data in Firebase .onSnapshot()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to set data with this function and its not setting the variable. How can I set information for outside use with this?

Here is my code

```
const docRef = store.collection('users').doc(item.email)
var image;
docRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        image = doc.data().picture
    }
})
```

How can I set the image variable within this function to use outside the onSnapshot? This is a React JS project.

Comment: You should set the variable in state and not just a simple var.. checkout [State hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: Why doesn't using a variable work?

Comment: The `onSnapshot` is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) so if you are returning the var before the data is loaded then it'll be undefined. If you set data in state then it'll update data wherever rendered

Comment: Ok that explains it

Comment: Also checkout [Why are the Firebase API asynchronous?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you should handle data in state

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react';

const [image,setImage] = useState('');
 const docRef = store.collection('users').doc(item.email);
 docRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
     if (doc.exists) {
        setImage(doc.data().picture) // Set Image Here
     } })
```

now you can work with image const outside the onSnapshot scoop